# Is there a way to refresh computer group membership without rebooting?

Tags: windows, active-directory, groups

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and have a windows service running under "network service" account in computer ComputerA. This windows service want to access a share folde (on another computer ComputerB) which grant read permission to a group GroupA. So I need to add the the computer account of ComputerA to the GroupA and restart the ComputerA.

My question is: is there a way to let the group membership immedialy take effect without restarting the ComputerA?

Answer (score 28):

```
For Windows 2008 and higher:

psexec -s -i -d cmd.exe

C:\Windows\system32>whoami
nt authority\system

-- List the session 0 tickets (0x3e7 is the machine session 0)
klist -lh 0 -li 0x3e7  

-- Purge the session 0 tickets  
klist -lh 0 -li 0x3e7 purge  

Should display:  

Current LogonId is 0:0x3e7  
        Deleting all tickets:  
        Ticket(s) purged!
```

PSExec is a free SysInternals download from Microsoft.

---

To clear up any confusion, this process absolutely will refresh the group memberships of a computer, and allow a group policy that applies to a security group to now apply to the computer, without rebooting the computer.  This has been tested and verified on Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2008 R2 and a universal security group.  The short version would be:

- `psexec -s -i -d cmd.exe`
- `klist tgt` (view the current ticket, make note of the size.  Also note that since you are running as system, the Current Logon Id is 0x3e7)
- Add the computer to the security group.  (Allow time to replicate, if applicable)
- `klist purge`
- `nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com` (run this or any other command that will connect to a network resource and force a TGT request)
- `klist tgt` (view the current ticket, make note of the size. It should be slightly larger.  Note that whoami /groups will not reflect the new membership)

At this point, it the system command prompt may be exited.

- `gpupdate /force`
- `gpresult /h gpresult.html`

View the gpreport, it should now show the group policy is applied.

Comment: I can confirm this just worked on Server 2012 R2 and Server 2016

Comment: Not working for me on Windows Server 2012 R2 (for both the member server, DCs, domain and forest functional level): I can purge the Kerberos tickets, but never got the new group (neither the `klist tgt` size changes, or `whoami /groups` reflects the new group). I've checked the change on the group is replicated through all the DCs.

Comment: Well, as per https://www.shellandco.net/blog/2016/07/07/update-computer-membership-without-reboot/#comment-8829, I've found none of those checks do reflect the new membership, but it's actually applied. This is true for my case: I can now execute the action depending on the new group, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I think restaring the netlogon service does the same thing, not sure what the overall impact would be.  Pretty sure that users would be temporarily disconnect users though.

Comment: For a Windows 7 workstation is this a solution without rebooting

Comment: In my experience restarting the service had no effect on the group membership.

Answer (score -1):

On my domain only works this for a network drive:

```
@echo off
net use M: /d /y
gpupdate /force
net use M: \\10.11.12.233\Archivos /persistent:Yes
explorer.exe M:
```