# gpupdate doesn't work on everything

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

On a Win2008 Domain Controller, I've changed an user account property
"Account is sensitive..."

Of course, I want that GPO to apply immediately

So I try **gpupdate** (or **gpupdate /force**), but it doesn't seem to work !?

I have to reboot my domain computer, then logon again with the user account to make it work !?

Another way ?

The solution is here 
[Is there a way to refresh computer group membership without rebooting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/159231/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-computer-group-membership-without-rebooting/159252#159252)

Comment: Seems like you are confusing Group Policy with Account properties

Comment: You're right, I thought Account properties were managed by GPO too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already commented, the "Account is sensitive and cannot be delegated" flag is a user account attribute, not a GPO setting.

If you've checked this box and want to make sure that the change is immediately replicated everywhere, you can use `repadmin` to force it:

```
repadmin /replsingleobj * source-dc01.domain.tld CN=SensitiveUser,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=tld
```

Comment: Ok, but doesn't work... I found that "klist purge" does the job !

Comment: It most certainly works, just not the way you expect :) The `repadmin /replsingleobj` command makes sure that the setting is replicated to all domain controllers, so that the *next* time you have a kerberos ticket issued, it takes effect. The setting itself does not retroactively update kerberos tickets